# Using Binomial Theorem to find the value of $ ^nC_0^2 - ^nC_1^2 + ^nC_2^2 - ^nC_3^2... + (-1)^n . ^nC_n ^2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

So I was solving problems in my textbook and I got stuck on this question. It says:

**Prove that:**

**$ ^nC_0^2 - ^nC_1^2 + ^nC_2^2 - ^nC_3^2 + ... + (-1)^{n} .^nC_n^2  $ = $ 0 $ or $ \frac {(-1)^{n/2} n!} {\frac{n}{2}! \frac{n}{2}!} $  ,**

when $ n $ is odd/even.

So I tried to bring the required terms and my idea was to multiply $ (1+x)^n $ with $(x - 1)^n$ .

$$ (1+x)^n = ^nC_0 + ^nC_1 x + ^nC_2 x^2 + ... ^nC_n x^n $$
$$ (x-1)^n = ^nC_0x^n - ^nC_1 x^{n-1} + ^nC_2 x^{n-2} + ... (-1)^n .^nC_n $$

I can see that if I multiply the two equations, then I will get the terms I need with their required sign.
LHS will contain $ (x^2 - 1)^n $  .

But along with that, there will be many other terms on the RHS which will probably be impossible for me to get rid of. Am I going in the right way or is there an entirely different procedure?

Comment: for $n=5$ : $1-3+6-10 \ne 0$

Comment: @aid78 for $ n=5 $ , its $ 1 - 25 + 100 - 100 + 25 - 1 = 0 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your $C$s are missing an index. Presuming that your sum is ${n\choose 0}^2-{n\choose 1}^2+{n\choose2}^2-\ldots$ $=\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j{n\choose j}^2$, then you're basically on the right track; I'd keep in mind that ${n\choose j} = {n\choose n-j}$ (which you seem to be doing implicitly) and write out the product that you have. Note that your sum will be exactly the $[x^n]$ term of this result - can you see why that would be so? Once you know that, you're almost home, because if two expressions are equal **as polynomials in $x$** then they'll be equal termwise, so you know that the $[x^n]$ term of $(1+x)^n(x-1)^n$ will be the same as the $x^n$ term of $(x^2-1)^n$.

Comment: Yeah so $ x^n $ of the expansion is my required sum

Comment: exactly. And that must be equal to the $x^n$ term on $(x^2-1)^n$, which you should be able to show is equal to the given answer - in other words, if $n$ is odd then this term is zero (why?) and if $n=2j$, say, it's $(-1)^j{2j\choose j}$.

Comment: I get that term as $ ^n C_\frac {n}{2} x^n (-1)^{n/2} $ . My answer comes if n is even, and for odd, $ ^n C_\frac {n}{2} $ does not exist. So I can directly conclude that it is zero, right?

Comment: Not exactly - it's more accurate to say that when $n$ is odd, the $[x^n]$ term of $(x^2-1)^n$ doesn't exist because $(x^2-1)^n$ is an even function and so only has even powers of $x$ in its expansion.

Comment: Yeah thanks. Answer accepted.